# Resources on ridgelets/curvelets

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

Can you suggest any good introductory resources on ridgelets and/or curvelets for image processing purposes?

I'm considering [buying](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521119138) [*Sparse Image and Signal Processing: Wavelets, Curvelets, Morphological Diversity*](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item2703288/) ([more](http://thames.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~fionn/Sparse_Signal_Recipes/)). Is there anyone who can recommend for or against it?

Comment: Looks interesting - please post a brief review if you do decide to get it

Comment: Does anyone else think that all these "give me a list of ideas/resources" questions aren't Real Questions?

Comment: @endolith: I was actually wondering about that myself, but I looked around and found several similar questions and therefore I decided to post this anyway.

Comment: @endolith Since this is a somewhat research oriented community, *some* reference-request question are certainly valid if posed correctly. Those certainly are popular and widely accepted on sites like Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found online, this paper is a pretty good intro to curvelets:
[Curvelets A Surprisingly Effective Nonadaptive Representation For Objects with Edges](http://jstarck.free.fr/curvencyclop09.pdf).

Another decent one I found was [Curvelets and Ridgelets](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/recover-curves-from-noisy-collection-of-points).

A quick Google search can lead you to a lot of good resources, and provided sufficient background, you can learn most of these things on your own. I'm sure there's more literature freely available out there.